# BUG or Mistake : Weird case of shape key

Tags: shape-keys

Iam trying a lip sync and my character doesnt lets me change the value of the shape key , i mean it does changed when i click and drag but it gets back to 0 again .

Here is the file :https://www.dropbox.com/s/j8vkahgn2lrco0v/error%20mouth.blend?dl=0

plz let me know the mistake iam doing in here

EDIT : So it turns out that when i double to open the file , shape key doesnt turn orange ( while changing the value ) . But when i open blender and import the file in it then it turns orange while changing the value .

Is it some kind of bug or what ??

Comment: you say that it doesn't let you change the value, but you have created shapekeys, so I'm not sure what you're talking about. You need to use "i" to create keyframes. The other point is that Blender can automatically create keyframes if the Automatic Keyframe Insertion is activated in the Timeline (button with a sphere next to play button & cie).

Comment: Yes i have added , but can you plz try adding more shape keys to the same girl character where it leads you when you double click the file .                     
 .So here is the thing , when i double click the .blend file to open it directly i cannot add shape keys . But when i open blender then import the same .blend file then the shape key works

Comment: if you're talking about creating new shapekeys, you need to be in Object mode to create a new shapekey, and not in Edit mode. Then go in Edit mode to move the vertices. Then back in Object mode you can play with the Value of the shapekey and create keyframes with "i".

Comment: sir iam talking about creating more key frames ( i want my character to talk ) using the talk shape key that i have already made . But if you use and see my blender file when trying to register a key frame for the shape " talk " its not registering . Can you plz check and let me know sir ?

Comment: it does work. When, in Edit mode, you're glad with your shapekey, you can come back to the Object mode. Now, put your cursor on the frame you want in the Dopesheet or Timeline. Then play with the value under the Shapekeys list, and when you have the value you want put your cursor on the value and press "i" to insert a keyframe. The new keyframe will be created as a yellow dot on the Dopesheet. The thing is that the shapekeys you've created are hard to see because it doesn't change the mesh a lot.